# Correct timestamp with milliseconds format in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp

What is the correct format to define a timestamp that includes milliseconds in Spark2?

```
val a = "2019-06-12 00:03:37.981005"
to_timestamp(a, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")   // 2019-06-12 00:03:37
to_timestamp(a, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FF6")   // null
to_timestamp(a, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFF")   // null
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
df.withColumn("aa", to_timestamp($"a", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")).show(false)
+--------------------------+----+
|a                         |aa  |
+--------------------------+----+
|2019-06-12 00:03:37.981005|null|
+--------------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had that problem once. Solved it by decreasing the precision of the ms. Not ideal but worked.

```
df.withColumn("tmp", substring($"a",1,23)).withColumn("res", to_timestamp($"tmp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).show()
```

**EDIT**

The OP pointed out that the previous line was just removing the ms. Try this out:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType

df.withColumn("tmp", substring($"a",1,23))
  .withColumn("res", (
                          unix_timestamp($"tmp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") + 
                          substring($"a", -6, 6).cast("float")/1000000
                     ).cast(TimestampType)
             )
```

Comment: This actually doesn't return null but the date without the milliseconds: 2019-06-12 00:03:37

Comment: Works fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As of what you can find [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-datetime.html#to_timestamp) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html), correct one is : `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`

Comment: still returns null.